# create data frame with columns being unique values in other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to convert my data frame so that the columns are unique lat values and rows are unique lon values with the values being the distance in r.

My original data frame is similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame( lat =c(0,0,0,25,25,25,30,30,30), lon =c(1,5,10,1,5,10,1,5,10), distance = c(20, 22, 25, 10, 12, 15, 5, 7, 9))
df
```

but i want to convert it into a form like this (although column names are not necessary)

```
final_df <- data.frame(lat0 = c(20,22,25), lat25 = c(10,12,15), lat30= c(5,7,9))
final_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tapply`:

```
t(tapply(df$distance, list(df$lat, df$lon), sum))
    0 25 30
1  20 10  5
5  22 12  7
10 25 15  9
```

If you want column names:

```
t <- as.data.frame(t(tapply(df$distance, list(df$lat, df$lon), sum)))
colnames(t) <- paste("lat", names(t), sep = "")
t
   lat0 lat25 lat30
1    20    10     5
5    22    12     7
10   25    15     9
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = lat, 
              names_prefix= "lat",
              values_from = distance)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    lon  lat0 lat25 lat30
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    20    10     5
2     5    22    12     7
3    10    25    15     9
```

add `select(-lon)` to remove this column after making the data "wide".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xtabs` as long as there is only one combination of *lat* and *lon*.

```
xtabs(distance ~ lon + lat, df)
#as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(distance ~ lon + lat, df)) #Alternative to get a data.frame
#    lat
#lon   0 25 30
#  1  20 10  5
#  5  22 12  7
#  10 25 15  9
```